# Mozilla Firefox Quantum v.66 - blocking all pages - Is there no solution to use the new version?

Tags: firefox, security, browser

OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit
Browser: Firefox 66.0.1

After last update to firefox v.66 i got only problems. It is blocking almost all pages.
I read about the security issue here: [Expect an increase in browser privacy and security warnings](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/08/24/expect-an-increase-in-browser-privacy-and-security-warnings/)

But i haven't thought that almost all websites will be blocked.

It blocks even its own pages. Examples: addons page, mozilla support page, blogspot, templatemonster and also my own websites.

I did placed exceptions for them, but there are still a lot of elements that are not working on the pages. And also in security option from the address bar it say that is not secure...

**Is there now chance to make the new Firefox working and do i really need to rollback to previous versions like v.62?**

I can't find any solution to that.

Examples:

[templatemonster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2XL7.jpg)

[firefox addons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Dl1.jpg)

[blogspot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fgca.jpg)

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 66.0.1

Comment: Firefox 66.0.1 works fine for me on several machines and OSes. Did you try removal and reinstallation? Did you try starting it up with a clean profile?

Comment: There's probably a problem with your certificates. Does your connection go through a proxy?

Comment: @wazoox Yes, that was the starting point. To have a true clean new installation because the old cache, favs and history were killing me for the new website. 
I also made a post on my blog regarding true Firefox uninstall. Until now, i haven't got any issues and i only update it in last 1-2 years. But now is killing me ;-( I can't have the second browser working fine.
I use Brave too but is too slow for the moment and is chrome related. And there are a lot of firefox users, so i need to check my website there too.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen No. It is a regular internet connection. No proxy no vpn... What certificates i own when i have only a browser and trying to surf different websites? 
I thought regarding my website that is my hosting provider "fault" after reading that article from main post. But when i entered in all other websites that i mentioned above it doesn't seem to have a problem with one website... Why is blocking their website too? And also, if you read that post isn't that suppose to block all things that "they don't agree"... but how to surf again?

Comment: Start up firefox with a clean profile by runnnig it from a command line in safe mode: `cd \program files\Mozilla\firefox` (or wherever you installed it) and `firefox --safe-mode`.

Comment: @ilvphoto yes, you do not technically own any certs, but the browser comes loaded with them. Those are the certs that browser knows it can trust. It is very essential part of surfing the web. When the browser doesn't the certs, it can cause similar problems that you face. However I don't know the answers for your questions, sorry. I would use Chrome until you get this solved.

Comment: @wazoox I did that. First i tried safemode and next refresh firefox. The same issues ;-(. I also tried random websites on a search and some are blocked some are not. I found that imdb.com is not blocked but the content is messed up. I also uninstalled again and delete everything and fresh reinstall. Don't tell me that you have it working well?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen I am using chrome and also as someone suggested, Waterfox. But the things that i'm afraid is to have my website not working for others if they are using Firefox. Are you using it and the websites above are working fine for you?

Comment: I tried the templatemonster site with Firefox 66 on Windows 10. No problems what so ever. I use Firefox daily and haven't got any of these errors. The templatemonster didn't even have a Symantec certificate and the green lock symbol was present. Are you sure that no one intercepting your requests? I think that your problems are not the same as on the link you provided.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen I don't know how to check that. But why it happens only on Firefox v. 66 and not the old one, also no other browser that i use: Chrome, Waterfox, Brave...? As i wrote in another place, could it be the antivirus that i use? I use Eset Smart Security 9.0.386. There are no errors there and also no messages regarding firefox or any of those security messages. I tried also to stop it with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what is likely a temporary work-around. The certificates presented by the OS's CA store are not being used anymore.

- Open a new tab and enter the following address:  about:config
- Accept the warning/notification.
- There is a search field at the top. Run a search for "security.enterprise_roots".
- Find an entry labelled "security.enterprise_roots.enabled".
- It is likely set to false. Set it to true.

In theory, that should bandaid your situation. I'm not sure what changed in Firefox, but it has affected an entire work environment on my end.

Comment: I tried it now and it works well. To everything that i tried. Is it safe to use it that way or should i try to uninstall the antivirus and reinstall it? Or maybe Eset Smart Security could be the issue?